# PHP application fails to read or set cookie on AJAX call from a different domain

Tags: ajax, cookies, cross-domain

I have a (.NET) application that calls a PHP app, residing on a different subdomain, via AJAX. 
To break down the problem, I wrote a simple test script:

```
<?php
setcookie('test', '1234', time()+60*60*24*30, '/', '.mydomain.com'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo 'Cookies: '; print_r($_COOKIE); 
?>
```

If called by direct request, the script behaves as expected - spits out an array with all the .mydomain.com cookies and sets the 'test' cookie.

Let's assume that I'm calling app2.mydomain.com/cookieTest.php from app1.mydomain.com/page1.aspx.

app1 is running on an IIS server, app2 on a Nginx (Linux) server.

So, on app1.mydomain.com/page1.aspx I run this JS:

```
$.ajax({
    'url' : 'https://app2.mydomain.com/cookieTest.php', 
    'success': function(r){
        $('#container').html(r); 
    }
});
```

The script returns an empty array for $_COOKIE and *attempts* to set a cookie but it fails. 
The response header looks like this:

```
Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:app2.mydomain.com
Origin:https://app1.mydomain.com
Referer:https://app1.mydomain.com/page1.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 21 Sep 2012 20:54:12 GMT
Server:nginx
Set-Cookie:test=1234; expires=Sun, 21-Oct-2012 20:54:12 GMT; path=/; domain=.mydomain.com
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

(note the set-cookie, which the browser ignores)

What can be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research ( http://www.bradchen.com/node/28 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control ) I realized that this is not achievable directly, but there are workarounds for both ways (getting and setting).

It's actually pretty easy: you can get the PHP app to read cookie values by passing a session ID or whatever else is in the cookies that we want to pass, and setting new cookies by parsing PHP's headers_list() and creating a JS that lets the browser set those cookies.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the origin url is **HTTPS** `Origin:https://app1.mydomain.com` and the destination url is **HTTP** `http://app2.mydomain.com/cookieTest.php` .

When I'm browsing a HTTPS site and the site wants to grab content from a HTTP one, or redirect to HTTP one, the browser alerts me and ask for my confirmation to do so. So it's possible your cookie is being blocked by that policies.

Comment: Actually that was my error in transcribing - I have tested with all-https or all-http solution, and that won't change the results. Thanks for pointing that out.